# How to call callback function with parameters?

Tags: javascript

I have a function:

```
function func1(callback){
   var num = 11111;
   callback.call(num);
}
```

Now i call it:

```
 func1(function(num){
    console.log("num= " + num);
 });
```

But i got that `num` is undefined.
Whats can be wrong?

Comment: First argument to call() is a "this" object. Try calling it callback.call(this, num).

Comment: You have used the [`call` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). Why? Just call it like a function: `callback(num)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Function.call()` will call the function with the scope of passed reference , you just need to call it not with any particular scope

```
function func1(callback){
   var num = 11111;
   callback(num);
}
```

Or if you want to call in any scope the first parameter is always reference , so pass your params after that, e.g.:

```
callabck.call(reference, param1, param2); 
callback.apply(reference, [param1, param2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because when you use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to call the callback function, the `num` is being set as the implicit `this` in the function being called, change to:

```
callback(num);
```

Instead of `callback.call(num);`.

From the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#Parameters)

> The value of this provided for the call to fun. Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, null and undefined will be replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be boxed.